# TDD code to force lazy initialization

Tags: c#, tdd, lazy-initialization

If I am to follow the test-driven development cycle, I must always write the test first, and then write the code. But then, if I have the following class:

```
public class ServiceProvider : IServiceProvider
{
    private readonly IService1 service1;
    private readonly IService2 service2;
    ...

    public ServiceProvider()
    {
        service1 = new Service1();
        service2 = new Service2();
        ...
    }

    public IService1 Service1 { get { return service1; } }
    public IService2 Service2 { get { return service2; } }
    ...
}
```

and a test that just checks that the instances returned are not null:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ServiceProviderTest
{
    [Test]
    public void ServicesAreNotNull()
    {
        var serviceProviderUT = new ServiceProvider();

        Assert.That(serviceProviderUT.Service1, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(serviceProviderUT.Service2, Is.Not.Null);
        ...
    }
}
```

how can I write a test that forces me to go from that class to the following one?

```
public class ServiceProvider : IServiceProvider
{
    private readonly Lazy<IService1> service1;
    private readonly Lazy<IService2> service2;
    ...

    public ServiceProvider()
    {
        service1 = new Lazy<IService1>(() => new Service1());
        service2 = new Lazy<IService2>(() => new Service2());
        ...
    }

    public IService1 Service1 { get { return service1.Value; } }
    public IService2 Service2 { get { return service2.Value; } }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test should not force you to do a specific implementation. It expects a certain behavior. For a unit test your code is a blackbox, if the behavior is correct the test succeeds. In this case the implementation of the services is private, so your test should not worry about how it is implemented. If the interface of a class is not changed, you should have the same unittests. The lazy initialization is more a code review item.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you talk about behavior, so I wonder if your answer may be more related about BDD and not TDD (I'm still trying to find the differences between them). Are you saying that there is no point in testing if a variable has been lazily initialized or not?

Comment: Well, in some cases you **might** want to validate if something is done lazy Example might be checking if `yield return` is used.

Comment: BDD is different thing. BDD is about the specification is in a given form. Given... When... Than... We don't test private stuff in TDD because we don't want to depend on implementation details

Comment: @CarlosAlejo the point is you are testing an interface. If the interface stays the same, the test should not change. That you are using lazy initialization is just an implementation detail.

Comment: So, if we return to the TDD cycle (write test, fail, write code, pass, refactor), the decision to make the variables lazily-initialized would be in the "refactor" step?

Comment: Yes, and your current unittest help you by verifying that your solution is still correct.